# On dimension of the Lie group $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, lie-groups

The following question appeared in an objective type exam.

> The dimension of the Lie group $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is

$(a) n^2 $

$(b) n^2-1$

$(c) 2(n^2-1)$

$(d) 2n^2$

Since i was supposed to choose one option so i clicked on option $(b)$ but in the answer key the answer is $(c)$. Probably they have considered it as real manifold. Can someone give me a proper precise reference of a book where the dimension is given as $n^2-1$ so that i can claim my answer should also be considered correct.

Comment: Unfortunately for your grade, “Lie group” in isolation usually means a real manifold, and otherwise people should add “complex” (not a great term) or “holomorphic.”

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what they meant by *dimension*: If they meant "dimension as a complex manifold" (or a complex Lie group), then (b) is the right answer, but if they meant "dimension as a real manifold" then it is (c). Similarly, one can ask "what is the dimension of ${\mathbb C}^n$?" If one treats ${\mathbb C}^n$ is a complex vector space, then it is $n$-dimensional, but as a real vector space, it has dimension $2n$. (It is infinite-dimensional as a vector space over ${\mathbb Q}$.)

Comment: Nothing was mentioned so what should be treated as answer?

Comment: @MathLover: The answer is that the question is ill-posed and that one should complain to the examiners.

Comment: I have done the same but I ain't sure whether they are going to change it or not.